# Movie file and audio file in Unity3d

Tags: c#, audio, unity-game-engine, mp4, ogg

I have a problem regarding the MovieTexture in Unity:
I want to load movie and audio files in Unity on the same game object (not simultaneously).
So, I have to differentiate between audio and video file, but I don't get it working. Here is what I want to do:

```
MovieTexture movieTexture;
AudioSource audio = gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>();
WWW file = new WWW(@"file:///"+pathToFile); //example.mp4 or example.ogg
if(movie)
{
    movieTexture = file.movie;
    gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = movieTexture;
    audio.clip = movieTexture.audioClip;
    movieTexture.Play();
    audio.Play();
}
if(audio)
{
    audio.clip = file.audioClip;
    audio.Play()
}
```

How can I do this?

I am using Unity 5.2 Personal Edition.

EDIT: I tried the suggestions, but it is still not working no matter what I do.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(file.movie != null)
{
    //logic for processing movie;
}
else if (file.audioClip !=null)
{
    //logic for processing audio;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, it is not working. `if(file.movie != null)` is always true, even if I only load a simple .ogg audio file. I saw, that if I try to load an audio file and it will be converting to a movie texture, Unity crashes at the point `movieTexture.Play();` with a bug report window. Do you know any alternative to this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I fix your code. First you check your `WWW` object `file.movie` whether it's null or not. If it's not null that means you already load a movie file. If it's null, check `file.audioClip` whether it's null or not. If it's not null that means you already load an audio file.

Please note that Unity only support Ogg Theora for movie texture loading (http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MovieTexture.html)

```
MovieTexture movieTexture;
AudioSource audio = gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>();
WWW file = new WWW(@"file:///" + pathToFile); //example.mp4 or example.ogg
if(file.movie != null)
{
    movieTexture = file.movie;
    gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = movieTexture;
    audio.clip = movieTexture.audioClip;
    movieTexture.Play();
    audio.Play ();
}
else if(file.audioClip != null)
{
    audio.clip = file.audioClip;
    audio.Play();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, it is not working. `if(file.movie != null)` is always true, even if I only load a simple .ogg audio file. I saw, that if I try to load an audio file and it will be converting to a movie texture, Unity crashes at the point `movieTexture.Play();` with a bug report window. Do you know any alternative to this?